# Is it possible to push up a div in a row to fill empty space of the above row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout problem, summarized in the images.
Practically, I have two rows containing span4 divs. The problem is that one div of the first row is too high and it dictates the height of the row. In the second row, I have a small div, which would be great if it could fill the empty space of the row above. Is there a css3 trick to do that?

Please, take a look at the images. I've added a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XmZwh/3/

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="sub1"> <a href=""><span class="icon-play"></span>item 1</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="sub1"> <a href=""><span class="icon-play"></span>items</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="sub1"> <a href=""><span class="icon-play"></span>item</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="sub1"> <a href=""><span class="icon-play"></span>item</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span11 offset1">
                            <div class="sub2"> <a href="">item
                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The html comes out of a dynamic construction of a menu, based on items stored in a CMS, so I don't have so much control over that.

[image: bad layout]

[image: desired layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to do this is by having a containing div that contains a and d,

Here is a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jQYtd/

```
<div class"cont">
<div class="cont2">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="d">D</div>
</div>

<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

and the css

```
.cont {
overflow:auto;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.cont2, #a, #b, #c {
float:left;
background-color:grey;
width:30px;
}
#a, #b, #c{
background-color:green; 
height:30px;
}
#c {
background-color:red;
height:60px;
}
```

if you have no control over the HTML you can use jquery to add `cont2` div

to do that via jquery you would do something like this

```
$( "#a, #d" ).wrapAll( "<div class='cont2'></div>" );
```