# Is there a way to make a div float up into an empty space in twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My question is similar to [stackoverflow.com question23013069](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013069/is-it-possible-to-push-up-a-div-in-a-row-to-fill-empty-space-of-the-above-row) except I **do** have control of the html. Row 1 has (A) col-sm-7 with a block div and (B) col-sm-5 with text. Row 2 has (C) col-sm-7 with a block div. Page looks good in md and lg sizes, but in the narrower sm size, the extended text of B creates a gap between A and C. Is there a way to remove that gap and make C float up? I don't want to move A and C to embedded rows in one column, because I want the mobile-size to stack in A,B,C order. [example](http://pamela.x10host.com/bnb/column-test.html)

```
<body>
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-7"> 
      <div style="max-width:500px;height:200px;border:thick solid blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas enim 
        lacus, luctus a urna ut, euismod tempus justo. Nulla elementum quis dui 
        at rutrum. Donec luctus eros et gravida pulvinar. Fusce facilisis purus 
        ac odio auctor, eget sollicitudin urna malesuada. Curabitur sollicitudin 
        vitae neque non placerat.</p>
      <p>Suspendisse pharetra quis nisl a sollicitudin. Aliquam vel iaculis ipsum, 
        vel ultrices leo. Nullam nec laoreet odio. Mauris non auctor justo. Quisque 
        sit amet malesuada ante. Sed at metus tellus. Ut auctor cursus lacinia. 
        Integer tempor sed mi ut ornare.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-7"> 
      <div style="max-width:500px;height:200px;border:thick solid red;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you'd like more specific help, create a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 1) clone the element and show/hide using utility classes, or 2) use a media query CSS statement to give that element a negative top margin to pull it up.

Comment: Thanks. I used your second solution and it fixed my problem completely. I don't have enough points to upvote.